# Assalamu alaikum Can I share a software that I’ve bought with a small forum for free

Tags: sin, software

I did share some softwares lately in a forum… but I feel somehow guilty I feel like I’m hurting the developer even tho I didn’t share the license code I share only the software for testing purpose or simple use. If someone want all features he may need to buy his own license. ( Legally I’m not allowed to share anything ).
In a way I’m helping the developer to get more sales if someone liked his software.
In another way there is people who bypass the license code and use the software with all features.. for free
I’m lost is it halal for me or shall I stop this.

Comment: So you are giving trial/demo/limited version without the consent of the developer/creator to others.

Comment: No I’m actually sharing the source code without the consent of the developer, but in order to run the source you’ll need to enter a valid license code. Basically forum users are using it for testing purpose